# Merge and Sort Contents of Dictionary in an Array

Tags: objective-c, sorting, merge

I have an array of dictionaries of options with categories. I want the options to be under the category. As of now, my categories are repeating as to how many times my options are added.

Given this:

```
(
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 4;
        multiOptnItem = 1344;
    },
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 7;
        multiOptnItem = 2253;
    },
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 4;
        multiOptnItem = 1343;
    },
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 4;
        multiOptnItem = 1346;
    },
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 4;
        multiOptnItem = 1342;
    },
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 4;
        multiOptnItem = 1345;
    }
)
```

What's the efficient way I can convert it to:

```
(
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 4;
        multiOptnItem = (1342, 1343, 1344, 1345, 1346);
    },
        {
        multiOptnCatId = 7;
        multiOptnItem = (2253);
    }
)
```

Thank you guys! :)

Comment: To not create the original array and then need to convert it is efficient. How are you creating it?

Comment: @Wain, thanks for replying. Im getting the data from the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = ...; // your input array

// All categories as array:
NSArray *catArray = [array valueForKey:@"multiOptnCatId"];
// All categories as set (to remove duplicates):
NSSet *catSet = [NSSet setWithArray:catArray];

NSMutableArray *rearranged = [NSMutableArray array];
// For all categories ...
for (NSString *cat in catSet) {
    // Get matching dictionaries for this category:
    NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"multiOptnCatId = %@", cat]];
    // Get "multiOptnItem" values for this category:
    NSArray *items = [filtered valueForKey:@"multiOptnItem"];
    // Add category + multiOptnItem values to rearranged array:
    [rearranged addObject:@{@"multiOptnCatId":cat, @"multiOptnItem":items}];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) :) :) I now have the desired data.